# Routing.navigate vs document.location.hash

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I have built a web app using `backbone.marionette`. When, from a `Marionette.ItemView`, I trigger the event `document.location.hash`:

```
 document.location.hash = '#tasks/' + this.model.get('id');
```

1.a) it changes the URL
1.b) it triggers the appRoutes

If I trigger the `Routing.navigate` from the same place:

```
router.navigate('#tasks/' + this.model.get('id'))
```

2.a) it changes the URL as expected
2.b) it does not trigger the appRoutes.

Any idea why 2.b happens? Where could the issue be?

Thanks.

```
var Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        'tasks': 'tasks',
        'tasks/:id': 'taskDetail',
        '*defaults': 'tasks'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `{trigger: true}`

```
router.navigate('#tasks/' + this.model.get('id'), {trigger: true})
```

Generally I extend the router and then add my own navigate that automatically adds that `{trigger: true}`. I understand why the developers did it like that, but it isn't the way I've ever used it :)

Comment: Thanks, actually this question is related to this one: [Circular Dependencies for a web app using backbone.marionette and requireJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265332/circular-dependencies-for-a-web-app-using-backbone-marionette-and-requirejs). And I would like to know how can I reach the same goal raising events.